# How to Count Integers With Padded Zeros

Tags: java, string, format, output

I want to count from `1` to `10` with a *variable* **width**.

Example for **width**: `4`

*Count Should Be:*

```
0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0008 0009 0010 ---> Note that it's not 00010
```

Example for **width**: `2`

Count Should Be:

```
01 ... 09 10 ---> Not 010
```

I've tried the following:

*First attempt*

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
   System.out.println("0".repeat(width-1) + i);
}
```

*Second attempt*

```
String output = String.format("%04d", 1);
```

These do not properly format numbers as the number of digits changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a format String with a variable length of format specifier. Adjust the width variable to whatever leading 0s you need.

```
int width = 2;
String format = "%0"+width+"d";

for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)  {
    String output = String.format(format, i);
    System.out.println(output);
}


/* Output:
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

A more flexible approach will be to provide `width`, `start` and `end` the sequence dynamically, so that none of the values will be hard coded.

A template for the output with the given width will be created by using string concatination.

```
public static void printZeroPaddedSequence(int start, int end, int width) {
    String template = "%0" + width + "d ";
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        System.out.printf("template", i);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printZeroPaddedSequence(1, 10, 4);
}
```

**Output**

```
0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0008 0009 0010
```